# How to Replace evrything exept text

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking to replace every thing except text between two string in php
example: Watch Sidney's video

i want to replace "Watch 's video" with nothing and just keep "Sidney"

need to be in this format preg_replace("regex code", "replace with", input text)

Comment: Will the two strings surrounding the text you want always be the same?

Comment: Watch 's video will be the same all the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using the following regex :

```
/Watch (\w*)'s video/
```

and you can replace with `\1`

Live demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/dGGrbh/2/)

**Update**

Sample code in php :

```
echo preg_replace('/Watch (\w*)\'s video/', "\\1", 'Watch Sidney\'s video');
```

**Output**

```
Sidney
```

Comment: sorry not working it will be in wordpress plugin option so cant put all this code right now im using    preg_replace("/\'s(.*)/", "", input text)   this code replace every thing except "Watch " and Sidney just need to replace "Watch " to

Comment: 1) you dont have to use all this code, you can simply substitute the value of all the variables in `preg_replace`. 2) you dont have "watch to" in your question, can you give a clear sample input and ouput? @RogerKaputnik

Comment: @RogerKaputnik also here's a working sample : https://ideone.com/4MYS8m , is this what's required?

Comment: preg_replace("/\'s(.*)/", "", Watch Sidney's video) > Watch Sidney    just need replace the word Watch

Comment: you can mark the answer as correct if it does answer the question correctly, helps future visitors find answers to their question. @RogerKaputnik

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of following `explode()` function for this:

```
$returnValue = explode(' ', 'Watch Sidney\'s video');
```

This  will return an array as:

```
array (
  0 => 'Watch',
  1 => 'Sidney's',
  2 => 'video',
)
```

Now check the entries of array for string with 's and once you get it, trim 's off as :

```
$myString  str_replace("\'s","",$returnValue[some_index]);
```

Comment: i will be using it in a wordpress plugin so it has to be in this format preg_replace("regex code ", "replace with", input)

Answer (score 0):

This'll give you the text between the first space and the first apostrophe (assuming these criteria are constant):

```
<?php
$message = "Watch Sidney's video";
$start = strpos($message, " ");
$finish = strpos($message, "'");
echo substr($message, $start, $finish-$start);
```

Comment: i will be using it in a wordpress plugin so it has to be in this format preg_replace("regex code ", "replace with", input)

Comment: Oh ok. How about: $answer = preg_match("/\s(.*?)'/", $message, $matches); echo $matches[1];

Answer (score 0):

```
// replace apostrophe (') or words without possessive contraction ('s) (Watch, video) with empty string
preg_replace("/(?:'|\s?\b\w+\b\s?)(?!'s)/", "", "Watch Sidney's video") // => Sidney
```

Try it here: https://regex101.com/r/sC7GyQ/1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract video author's name - you may use extracting preg_match like this:

```
$matches = [];
preg_match('@Watch (\w+)\'s video@', $source, $matches);

echo $matches[1];
```